# Сan't make the "::before" pseudo-element go after "::after"

Tags: html, css

Here's what's shown on the layout:

[image: layout]

And here's what I did:

[image: result]

There's no difference between the layout and the site I made, but when it comes to adaptive..

[image: adaptive]

Here's the code:

```css
.expertise__content{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 130px;
}

.expertise__content-items{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 30px;
}

.expertise__content-item{
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #1D1D1D;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 370px;
  max-width: 370px;
  border-top: 2px solid #1D1D1D;
  position: relative;
}

.expertise__content-item::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F0F0F0;
  width: 10%;
}

.expertise__content-item::after{
  content: "90%";
  padding-left: 262px;
}

#expertise__content-item-two::before{
  width: 20%;
}

#expertise__content-item-three::before{
  width: 15%;
}

#expertise__content-item-two::after{
  content: "80%";
  padding-left: 244px;
}

#expertise__content-item-three::after{
  content: "85%";
  padding-left: 218px;
}
```

```html
<div class="expertise__content">
  <div class="expertise__content-items">
    <div class="expertise__content-item" id="expertise__content-item-one">BRANDING</div>
    <div class="expertise__content-item" id="expertise__content-item-two">DESIGN</div>
    <div class="expertise__content-item" id="expertise__content-item-three">DEVELOPMENT</div>
  </div>
```

How do I make the percentages go exactly after the line above `expertise__content-item`?

Tried to solve the problem by using `padding-left: ...%;`, but it didn't help

Comment: What do you mean by "when it comes to adaptive"?

Comment: I don't know how to say what I mean correctly in English, I had to use a translator. So, what I meant to say was that when I started making the site adaptive, the line over the "expertise__content-item" element went forward and the percentages stayed behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider a different idea with less of code. I am relying on a CSS variable to adjust every in the code so all you have to do is to update that variable.

I am assuming you have enough space for both text and percentage otherwise it won't render well.

```css
.progress {
  font-family: monospace;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  /* the gradient will create the progress bar*/
  background:
    linear-gradient(90deg, #000 calc(var(--p)*1%), #ccc 0)
    top/100% 2px no-repeat;
  /* flexbox to place the content */  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.progress:after {
  content: attr(style) "%"; /* show the content of the variable */
  /* trim the first 4 charater (--p:)*/
  text-indent: -4ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  /**/
  /* the margin will push the value from the right to place it correctly */
  margin-right: calc((100 - var(--p))*1%);
  /* transform will make sure we have the number centred */
  transform: translate(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress" style="--p:80">Branding</div>
<div class="progress" style="--p:50">Design</div>
<div class="progress" style="--p:65">Development</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, everything worked the way I wanted it to, but there is one problem - when I pass a value in the attribute "style" of the element that I want, the whole value is passed, including the name of the variable (--p). To make it clearer to you, here's a link to a [screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/ZNFfbSQ/msedge-s-Agm-GAq-Hom.png)

Comment: @IsmailN9 that's why I am using text-indent and overflow to trim the non-needed part (read the comment in the code)

Comment: Indeed, revised the code and slightly changed the value of the property "text-indent", now everything is exactly as it should be. Thank you!